# What is the meaning of 0x1234ABCD when working with raw bytes

Tags: java, bit

When dealing with byte operations in Java, I saw sometimes that people masked a 0xFFFFFFFF long value (32bit value) with 0x1234ABCD

I know that Java does not support unsigned integer values (except char) but I would like to understand the meaning (if any) of these numbers 0x1234ABCD and 0xABCD1234 and also what is the significance to use them when working with raw bytes in Java?

Comment: You're asking us to explain code you aren't showing us.

Comment: Those are just integer constants expressed as hexadecimal... What is the mystery in that?

Comment: I'm talking about the specific value "0x1234ABCD" I want to know what it means! I've seen it crop up numerous times

Comment: That depends on the code; it may be some magical value, just like `0xdeadbeef`. Without seeing the code, no one can tell.

Comment: Do a google search and you will see it used as a value in various introductory computer classes. I think it is because it will be easy to see if the answer to a particular problem is correct without having to memorize or deal with an arbitrary string of mixed numbers and letters. No magic as far as I can tell.

Comment: @fge The first time I saw 0xdeadbeef it was on the IBM RS-6000 workstation running AIX. The claim was that it was an illegal floating point value. AIX would fill unitialized locations in your application space as an aid to the programmer in finding program errors that referenced uninitialized memory. It is also very easy to spot in a memory dump. Personally I like to use a "Signaling NaN" value that is supposed to generate an interrupt or exception when used in calculations.

Comment: Alright, All I wanted to know was whether or not there was a certain significance to that number 0x1234ABCD, but it seems not. thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are asking but anyway...

With Java, integer values (whether that be `byte`, `short`, `char`, `int` or `long`) are expressed as big endian, two's complement signed values. What you see here is another way than the decimal way of expressing such constants.

For instance, 28 as an `int` is internally represented as:

```
binary: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1100
hex:       0    0    0    0    0    0    1    c
= 0x1c
```

Which means these two are equivalent:

```
int i = 28;
int i = 0x1c;
```

It is useful to express integer constants as hexadecimal when working with bit masks, because with a little habit, you can "translate" from hexadecimal to binary. For instance, when you want an integer with the last 4 bits of another one, it is more obvious what you do if you write:

```
i & 0xf
```

rather than:

```
i & 15
```

`0xffffffff` is -1 (or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`).

Comment: to make sure that I'm not misunderstanding, this would create a new number with the last four bits being 1?

Comment: No, this will create an int with the last 4 bits. `0xf` is `0000 .... 1111`. It will "extract" the last `.... xxxx` from the other number. `28 & 0xf` for instance will return 12 (0xc). This is a bitwise and operation. In a bitwise and, for any bit `x`, `x & 1` is `x` and `x & 0` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you calculate something, you´re dealing with numbers.
10 Dollars, 50 percent, 20 degree Celsius.
And the "nexadezimal" notations is just another way to write these numbers.
0xA Dollar, 0x32 percent, 0x14 degree Celsius.
What they mean depends on what you´re doing.
Calculating your money, temperature or something else.

When dealing with "raw byte" stuff, it´s often just more convenient
to write hex. numbers instead of normal decimal one´s,
because in such cases, they can actually improve readability.
Like 0x80000000 instead of 2147483648